# Ruby on Rails router weirdness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a Rails 3 app with a non-model based controller I'm using to serve up a series of slides.  The SlideController figures out the proper ID for the previous & current slide, then feeds that ID to a link_to helper in the view for forward & back buttons.

The tooltip over the forward button on the first page reads: http://localhost:3000/slide/2/.  When I right-click on it, choose "Copy link location" and paste it in address bar, it works.  When I call the url via javascript, it works.  When I click on it, it fails with the the message

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/slide/slide/2")

Wondering if it was a problem with my local server, I deployed to Heroku, and got the same error.

Why does this link look perfected formatted, but it's not being handled by the router how I'm expecting???

Thanks!

routes.rb

```
RadioDose::Application.routes.draw do
    get "/slide/:id" => "slide#show", :as => 'slide'
    get "/slideshow" => "slide#show"
end
```

slide_controller.rb

```
class SlideController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @id = (params[:id].blank? ? '1' : params[:id])
        @slide_name = 'slide' + @id
        max_slide = 40
        @last_slide = (@id.to_i > 1 ? @id.to_i - 1 : 1)
        @next_slide = (@id.to_i < max_slide ? @id.to_i + 1 : max_slide)
    end
end
```

show.html.erb

    `<%= render :partial => @slide_name %>
    
      <%= link_to 'Back', slide_path(@last_slide), :id => 'left-arrow', :class => 'sprite' %>
      <%= link_to 'Next', slide_path(@next_slide), :id => 'right-arrow', :class => 'sprite' %>
    
     Page <%= @id %> 
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'slide' %>`

Comment: Please add the output of `rake routes` to your question.

Comment: I think it's coming from your JS, do you mind copy/pasting some significant part of it?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you pasted tells you everything you need to know. When you click on the link, you're being directed to `http://localhost:3000/slide/slide/2` rather than `http://localhost:3000/slide/2`. Given that the link is working when you copy and paste it, and that you're using the standard `slide_path` suggests that the link is correct in the HTML, but something is happening to break it in your javascript.

It's probably just a simple case of the URL being treated as relative to the current page, rather than relative to root.

Incidentally, you could still use RESTful routes here, even if your slides aren't backed up by a database. If your whole app is a single slideshow, use:

```
RadioDose::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :slides
end
```

or if you want to support multiple slideshows, then:

```
RadioDose::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :slideshows do
      resources :slides
   end
end
```

Then you could display the first slide from either the `index` action of the Slides controller, or in the second example, the `show` action of the Slideshow controller.